# How do I compare a pointer value to raw value

Tags: go, pointers

I get the Count variable from another library.

```
var Count *int64
    
val1 := int64(5)
    
Count = &val1
```

If I have to compare Count to another value in my code, how do I do it?

This does not work

```
if Count > 3 {
    fmt.Println("Count is greater than 5")
}
```

Neither does this. Error message is - "cannot compare Count > pVal (operator > not defined for *int64)"

```
zValue := int64(3)
pVal := &zValue

if Count > pVal {
    fmt.Println("Count is greater than 5")
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if *Count > 3 {
    fmt.Println("Count is greater than 5")
}
```

Quoting from [the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Pointer_types):

> For an operand x of pointer type *T, the pointer indirection *x
> denotes the variable of type T pointed to by x.

Comment: Here's a playground link https://play.golang.org/p/l4YhtZ9oED2